# Move AWS Resources to another Account

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

We are running various AWS resources currently in an account namely but not limited to :

EC2 (we can copy AMIs), RDS,VPC,IAM, S3, SNS, CloudWatch, CloudFront,Auto Scaling

we now want to move everything to another AWS Account. How Do I move all?

I need to get the S3 Buckets synced and so does CloudFront.

I was trying to get hold off CloudFormation and generated a CloudFormer Template. Then I imported the template to new AWS Account and Launched a new Stack out of this Template.

What's next ??

I can't see EC2 Servers created, nor S3, security group, EBS, nothing is there on the new account.

How do I move all the resources in one go ?

Thank you.
Sandeep

Comment: You can't move S3 buckets from account to account. You can't move EC2 instances either, but you can make an AMI and grant the other account access to that.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Yes I am aware of AMI and I can even get hold off S3 buckets by something called s3cmd and by first granting access to new account then do the sync.  Edit: Since I have many resources to move I am thinking of using CloudFormation Stacks. That's where I need the real help now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build your entire infrastructure with CloudFormation you could more easily replicate it, even in another account.

You still need to deal with data migration, which will be different depending on your deployment setup.

If you use configuration management most if not all of your OS can be replicated in your other account too.

While AWS does have a method of reverse engineering a CloudFormation template based on your current environment I've never tried it, sounds like you should give it a go.

The aws cli has commands to move s3 data "aws s3 sync s3://from s3://to". You may need to export or otherwise share other data like RDS and SNS.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to [contact AWS Support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/transfer-aws-account/) for this:

> If you want to assign ownership of the account and its resources to
>   another party or organization, contact AWS Support for help:
>
> 1. Open the AWS Support Center.
> 2. Choose Create case.
> 3. Enter the details of your case:
>
>    For Regarding, choose Account and Billing Support.    For Service,
>      choose Account.    For Category, choose Ownership Transfer.
> 4. For all other fields, enter the details for your case.
> 5. Choose a contact method, and then choose Submit.
>
> AWS Support will contact you using the method that you selected and
>   help you transfer your account to another party.

Comment: If you do so, all they will tell you is how to transfer every single ressources manually